# Cells of numpy array in DataFrame are stored as strings

Tags: arrays, string, pandas, dataframe, cell

One column of my `pandas.DataFrame`s stores `numpy.array`s, which means each cell within that column has a `numpy` `array` style like `[a1, a2, a3, ...]`. I write this `DataFrame` to disk through `pd.to_csv(filename)`. However, when I read the file with `pd.read_csv()`, the type of that cell becomes string instead. Does anyone know how to read in the cell as `numpy.array`?

Comment: Have you tried using `dtype` keyword argument to `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: Csv isn’t meant for storing array like data. It has no way to store the associated meta data. To solve your csv problem, do a search [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+read+string+as+array+from+csv). Otherwise, might be better to store data as json

Comment: Yes, I tried. It gives an error: dtype np.ndarray not understood

Comment: Ugly workaround to your problem: read as strings and do `import ast` and `df['col_name'].transform(ast.literal_eval)`. However, I'd follow @piRSquared's advice

Comment: Thanks @RafaelC, those arrays are actually numbers, and literal_eval doesn't work here either. I will follow piRSquared's advice

Comment: Unless you must use a csv, it might be a better idea to looking into [pickles](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html).